# How do I fix a Vue devServer proxy to a Web API with windows authentication that inconsistently gets a 401 error?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, vuejs3, webpack-dev-server

I am developing a vue 3 intranet application that communicates with a web api that uses windows authentication. In production, the vue application and api are both hosted on IIS on the same server with the api being an application under the vue application.

The issue is when I'm hosting it locally, I have an iis express instance for the api and a nodeJS instance for the vue interface. To imitate production, I have a devServer proxy set up in the vue.config.

`

```
const https = require('https');
const HttpsAgent = require('agentkeepalive').HttpsAgent;

const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const baseFolder =
    process.env.APPDATA !== undefined && process.env.APPDATA !== ''
        ? `${process.env.APPDATA}/ASP.NET/https`
        : `${process.env.HOME}/.aspnet/https`;

const certificateArg = process.argv.map(arg => arg.match(/--name=(?<value>.+)/i)).filter(Boolean)[0];
const certificateName = certificateArg ? certificateArg.groups.value : "OLBMonitorWeb";

if (!certificateName) {
    console.error('Invalid certificate name. Run this script in the context of an npm/yarn script or pass --name=<<app>> explicitly.')
    process.exit(-1);
}

const certFilePath = path.join(baseFolder, `${certificateName}.pem`);
const keyFilePath = path.join(baseFolder, `${certificateName}.key`);

module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        https: {
            key: fs.readFileSync(keyFilePath),
            cert: fs.readFileSync(certFilePath),
        },
        proxy: {
            '/webapi': {
                target: 'https://localhost:44394',
                logLevel: "debug",
                changeOrigin: true,
                agent: new HttpsAgent({
                    maxSockets: 100,
                    keepAlive: true,
                    maxFreeSockets: 10,
                    keepAliveMsecs: 100000,
                    timeout: 6000000,
                    freeSocketTimeout: 90000
                }),
                onProxyRes: proxyRes => {
                    var key = 'www-authenticate';
                    proxyRes.headers[key] = proxyRes.headers[key] && proxyRes.headers[key].split(',');
                },
                pathRewrite: { '^/webapi': '' }
            }
        },
        webSocketServer: 'ws',
        port: 5002,
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        hot: true
    }
}
```

`

It works, but unreliably. Sometimes I can browse the site just fine, other times I have to reload the page repeatedly to get past the 401 error.

If I type in my credentials, sometimes, rarely, I get through. Usually I get my account locked out and have to get my password reset, so I don't even try anymore. I have tried adjusting the times for the devserver agent but that only seems to delay the the next 401 error after I successfully get authenticated. Other than that, I've tried various rearrangements of the devServer settings, turning off McAfee, and I'm not sure what else since this has been going on for months. As far as I and my coworker can tell, this should work. But, obviously we're missing something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an unsatisfying answer, but the solution was to change the company's firewall.

We were using a proxy for the company's network traffic, but now we don't. That somehow fixed the problem. I've had multiple people from our network department leave without any proposed solution or even a proposition of why it was behaving as it did.